# "cover the unit sphere by c-fine grid" to prove the vector length preserved by random projection?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, random-variables

The below figure is extracted from the paper http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4031351 . I did not understand the techniques used in the proof, namely,

1."cover the unit sphere with a finite set";

2.the definition of "$c$-fine grid on $[-1,1]^k$".

Can someone take some time to help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Covering is a standard technique to obtain bounds on the supremum of random processes. In Lemma 10 the author is essentially showing that the map $S$ is isometric restricted to the subspace. Isometry is ensured by the fact that $S$ is a JL transform. JL transform applies to a finite set of points however if you cover the subspace (rather the unit sphere over the subspace) dense enough than you can also show that even the supremum and infimum is almost isometic which is the equation the author states. I suggest that you read Vershynin's tutorial that illustrates how these kind of ideas can be used in random matrix theory http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3027. After reading this, you might have a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is still hard to find the definition of "c-fine grid".